# How do I get the version code I want into Visual Studio using Mercurial

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, mercurial

I will start by saying this is probably a dumb question so apologies if I am staring at the answer but cannot see.

I have used VCS in the past primarily as a method of allowing me to revert my code if something goes wrong.  I have always had a single lime of development.  However I get into the usual trouble when releasing and starting the next version - dealing with bugs.  So this time I decided to use branching (forking or whatever is the best name).  I am a lone developer so I am the only one working with the repositiory.  My scenerio is simple.  I want to create a branch when I release so that I have a line for the released code and a line for the beta.  I can then work happily on the beta.  Now a bug comes in and I need to get back to the last commit for the release.

My question is what is the best way to get back that code in the IDE to work on it.

I have read that in Mercurial a simple way is to clone the repository including the working directory.  This would give me two copies of the code base and I guess I can choose which one to load into the IDE.  I would then use Push or pull to get the bug fixes from the release copy into the beta copy (I think).

I assume there must be another way however without cloning.  How would I do that?  I can guess at reverting to the last commit of the release code.  Then I assume that loading the solution into the IDE would give me that.  I am not sure where I would go from there when the code is done.

For the record I looked at a number of different VCS - I have used SVN in the past but wanted to go to a DVCS.  I looked at Git, Bazaar, Mercurial and Veracity (and used Code-Coop in the past).  You may think another tool would suit my needs better.  Having tried the others however I found I could understand the way Mercurial works and the GUI tools such as TortoiseHg with the WorkBench and HgSccPackage (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9bc074fa-9e1f-4ce2-a75d-b90e65f7475a) appeal

There are a lot of good documents and links here [Introduction to Mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837858/introduction-to-mercurial)  and I have read about different ways to branch that include using bookmarks and so on but they seem primarily targeted at multi member teams - which make sense of course

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing concepts a little, i guess you have SVN background ?

Just to answer you question, to 'get back the code in IDE' you will need to 'update' to a previous version. But this is considering you already have cloned the repository. Is your question about how to clone.. ? As you ask, there is no other way without cloning first. Cloning is the first step towards having a HG repository local. After clone, you can commit and push changes or pull and update.

To expand the answer even further and given that you are going to use Mercurial, here is what you should do:

- read this : http://hginit.com/ - great HG (tutorial) by Joel Spolsky him self ! An introduction into HG and the concepts. You will need to understand this very good, since right now you are doing a lot of guessing, assuming and thinking :) HG/Git is different from SVN and in the begging the concepts might be hard to understand and to get used to.
- for your project and regarding your question, have a branch called 'dev' or 'trunk' or 'version X' etc  where you will commit all new changes.
- have a branch called 'live' etc that will represent the current 'live' version. This way, whenever you need to revert back in time to the live version and to do a quick fix on it, you will 'update' to the tip of that 'live' branch, discarding all local changes (after you have committed to trunk! of course).
- when putting a version to live, you will need to (assuming all changes are committed !) : update to the live branch then MERGE the version X into local (local being live ). This will include your versionX branch into live - it's what you need at this point. Then, either update back to version X branch or create a new branch - version X+1. This will take care of the versions and keeping the branches separate.
- since you are using VS - install http://visualhg.codeplex.com/. HG source control integrated into VS.

Comment: Thanks - not really about cloning - I know how to do that.  My basic question is how to have a release set of code and a beta set of code under Mercurial and get the right set into the IDE.  I think I know how to do that with a clone but I want to know if there is a proper way to do it from a single uncloned repository.  I am not surprised my concepts are mixed!

Comment: Uncloned repository ? You don't want to keep your sources on an external mirror ? Yes, you can work with just your local repo (i've never done that).
Your question is clearer now and my answer edited. Hope it's what you need.

Comment: It's just a name so it's not too important but typically the branch for the live code is called `stable` for Mercurial.

Comment: Thanks for the input! What about the rest of the advice ? I'm not new to HG, i just want to know how others use it.

Comment: It looks good but the main development branch should be called `default` as that is the branch that is set to be the working copy after a clone.

Answer (score 1):

> I assume there must be another way however without cloning

Yes. You can use (named) branches inside single repo (I prefer [HgSccPackage](https://bitbucket.org/zzsergant/hgsccpackage/wiki/ScreenShots) in VS), update to <strike>revision</strike>branch head, change, commit, merge

BTW, branching with bookmarks/clones/branches work the same (good) way for any size of team - it's a matter of taste

Comment: I am using HgSccPackage also.  It supports VS2012 but as far as I can tell VisualHg does not at the moment.  I think I need to create a test project and try some of these things out